# Número de repetições dentro de um array

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando contar quantas vezes um elemento aparece dentro de um array.

```
`   
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[4];
    int a;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Digite um numero: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        array[i] = a;
    }
    System.out.println("Seu array ficou: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        int vezes = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                        if(array[i] == array[j] && i!=j){
                            int numero = array[i];
                            vezes++;
                            while(array[i]==array[j] && vezes>1){
                                System.out.println("O numero "+numero+" é repetido "+vezes+" vezes.");
                                vezes=0;
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
}`
```

Nesse meu exemplo eu só consigo fazer ele mostrar elementos que se repetem 2 vezes corretamente, isso acontece por causa que eu igualo vezes=0 quando ele se repete mais de uma vez.
Como posso fazer pra que ele não caia dentro do `while(array[i]==array[j] && vezes>1)` até que passe por todos os elementos repetidos? Podendo usar um "if" também.

Se preenchido com os números 1,1,1,2 por exemplo já da errado.

Comment: Meio confuso de entender. Tente postar como seria a saída do seu algoritmo aqui para facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar você só poderia imprimir depois de realizar todas as contabilizações. Para isso, seria necessário salvar tudo que você contabilizou e então apenas imprimir a variável que armazenou essas contabilizações. Uma possível solução seria ajustar teu código para o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[4];
    List<Integer> numerosJaContabilizados = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> numeroRepeticoes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int a;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite um numero: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        array[i] = a;
    }
    System.out.println("Seu array ficou: " + Arrays.toString(array));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j && !numerosJaContabilizados.contains(array[i])) {
                registrarNumeroRepeticao(array[i], numeroRepeticoes);
            }
        }
        numerosJaContabilizados.add(array[i]);
    }
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> numeroRepeticao : numeroRepeticoes.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(
                "O numero " + numeroRepeticao.getKey() + " é repetido " + numeroRepeticao.getValue() + " vezes.");
    }
}

private static void registrarNumeroRepeticao(int numero, Map<Integer, Integer> numeroRepeticoes) {
    if (numeroRepeticoes.get(numero) != null)
        numeroRepeticoes.put(numero, numeroRepeticoes.get(numero) + 1);
    else
        numeroRepeticoes.put(numero, 2);
}
```

As mudanças feitas:

1. Adicionada uma variável para armazenar as repetições dos números: numeroRepeticoes. Perceba que é um map pois aí dá pra usar como chave o número e como valor as repeticões.
2. Adicionada uma variável para contabilizar os números já processados: numerosJaContabilizados. Teu while de impressão seria mais ou menos pra isso, mas a lógica iria quebrar se o número repetido não viesse em ordem sequencial. Para isso é melhor utilizar uma variável que armazene essas contabilizações e seja usada para verificar se o número deve ser contabilizado ou não.
3. Adicionada impressão dos valores FORA dos laços. Assim você irá imprimir o resultado apenas depois de processar tudo.

Esse foi um exemplo de como teu método iria funcionar, mas aqui vão algumas sugestões:

1. Refatore o método: Teu método main tem muitas responsabilidades, o ideal era dividí-las pelo menos entre métodos diferentes. Por exemplo, uma responsabilidade poderia ser a leitura dos dados, a outra seria a contabilização de repetições e a outra seria a impressão das repetições. É um exercício interessante tentar modularizar ao máximo um método. Eu recomento ;)
2. Utilize a API collections: Vi que você usa arrays com tipos primitivos mas assim você perde o poder que a API collections te dá! Inclusive utilizando ela você resolveria teu problema em poucas linhas de código, mas aí não ficaria muito didático por isso é melhor tentar implementar a lógica do zero mesmo.

Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: 10/10. Só daria mais uma sugestão para o autor da pergunta. Dê um empenho maior na nomeação, como a @Giuliana fez. Assim ficará mais organizado e você não precisará se preocupar em saber o que vai aonde.